# How to get the value of the selected radio button in angular

Tags: angular

What's the best way to get the value of the selected radio button in angular?
[This link](https://juristr.com/blog/2016/11/ng2-binding-radiobutton-lists/) shows the implementation with data binding.
I just want to get the value in `onSelectionChange` method which is the `change` event handler.
Maybe I can code as the following:

`<input type="radio" value="beauty" (change)="onSelectionChange($event)" checked>`

```
  private onSelectionChange(event) {
    alert(event.srcElement.value);
  }
```

Is it a good practice?

Comment: Depends on the implementation of you'r forms i guess. For example, if you create a reactive form, you want to handle them directly with `formControlName` or with a template-driven forms by a two-way data binding.

Comment: Agree with @bishop. Eventually something like `<input type="radio" value="beauty" (click)="onSelectionChange(beauty.value)" checked #beauty>` should also work

Comment: @bishop Actually, I'm not familiar with `reactive form` and `template-driven form`. In my search page, I just want to get the value from an radio.

Comment: @niaomingjian, if it's just for that, you can probably handle the changement by a (change) event. I answered at the question, 'what is the best way', and in fact in angular, is how you handle your own forms. In the futur you'll probably want to use a checkbox in a classic form, and the (change) event will not be the best solution.